# Creating a view with Domain object fields

Tags: grails

I have the following domain classes.

```
Address

String number
String roadName
String country

Person

String fName
String age
Address address
```

I have a view called `PersonViewSave` i want the user to be able to save `Person` information from this view. When creating a `Person` record the user needs to create a `Address` record as well.

My Person controller looks like this:

```
PersonViewSave ={
    def ad = new Address(number: '11', roadName: 'round road', country:'France').save()
    new Person(fName: 'Alex', age: '23', address:ad).save()

}
```

1.) How do i collect parameters from the view and bring it to the `PersonViewSave` method ? (And can someone show me a sample GSP view file with the `Person` and `Address` textfields)

2.) Incase if there's an error in the Address created, how do i prevent creating a Person object with an address as shown in this line `new Person(fName: 'Alex', age: '23', address:ad).save()`

**UPDATE**

```
    <g:form name="myForm" method="post" action="doIt">
<p>Person info:</p>

<label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <g:textField name="firstName" id="firstName" />




<p>Address Info:</p>

<label for="roadName">Street Number</label>
    <g:textField name="roadName" id="roadName" />


<g:submitButton name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Here, i have only used few objects from the Domain classes just to see if it works.

I also have a parameter called createdDate in both Domain classes. That as well needs to be auto inserted.

My Service Class is as follows:

```
def saveService () {

def ad = new Address(params)
if (ad.save(flush: true)) {        
    def p = new Person(params)
    p.address = ad
    p.save()
} else {
    // display validation errors
}
}
```

1.) I get an error and it is > `No such property: params for class: pro.PersonService`

2.) What hapence i have 2 domain class with parameters that has the same Name. For example `Animal` and `Person` domain classes have an parameter called `firstName`. According to your previous solution how will grail distinguish to what domain class it belongs to ?

**I am using Grails 2.2.4**

Comment: You could use the `grails generate-all` command (http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/ref/Command%20Line/generate-all.html) to have it spit out controller and views for your two objects to see how the default scaffolding works (http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/scaffolding.html)

Comment: Which version of Grails are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to check that the Address saved correctly:

```
def ad = new Address(params)
if (ad.save(flush: true)) {        
    def p = new Person(params)
    p.address = ad
    p.save()
} else {
    // display validation errors
}
```

This returns the `Address` if it saved properly, which results in `true`, otherwise it returns `null` (or `false`).

Also, you can use data binding via the `params` map to create your objects from parameters. As long as the key in `params` matches up to a property name in your `Address` and `Person` class, the value of the parameter will be assigned to the object.

So, for instance, to map your `Person`, you will need fields like the following:

```
<g:form name="personForm" method="post" action="PersonViewSave">
    <p>Person info:</p>

    <label for="fName">First Name</label>
        <g:textField name="fName" id="fName" />

    <label for="age">Age</label>
        <g:textField name="age" id="age" />


    <p>Address Info:</p>

    <label for="number">Street Number</label>
        <g:textField name="number" id="number" />

    <label for="roadName">Road</label>
        <g:textField name="roadName" id="roadName" />

    <label for="country">Country</label>
        <g:textField name="country" id="country" />

    <g:submitButton name="submit" value="Submit" />
</g:form>
```

Comment: I also want to have the `Address` fields displayed in the view. So a user can create a new address when their creating a new `person`. So how can i do this?

Comment: Simple, just add `g:textField` tags for each property of Address. Let me edit my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: Edited. Because the names of those fields in the form correspond to property names in the Address and Person classes, you can use databinding to create each object. `def p = new Person(params)` is the same as going `def p = new Person(fName: params.fName, age: params.age)`.

Comment: No still stuck. Its not getting saving. I will update my code.

Comment: Please add which version of grails you are using in your question and any errors that you are receiving.

Comment: Ah, I was under the impression this logic was happening from a controller action. `params` is only available in controllers, so you will need to pass it to the service for it to data bind (`def myService(params)`). As for multiple Domain classes on one page, I believe you can prefix your textFields with the class name. See [this article on the Grails website](http://grails.org/Editing+multiple+domain+objects+on+the+same+page) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
def ad = new Address(number:params.number , roadName:params.roadName , country: params.country)
if (ad.save(flush: true)) {        
    def p = new Person(fName:params.fName , age: params.age, address:ad)
       p.save()
} else {
    // display validation errors
}
```

Comment: This is what i get `No such property: params for class:  pro.PersonService` I have wrote this in the service class.

Comment: You need to pass params from controller to service. eg controllermethod = { myservice.saveService(params){  //do here}  }

Comment: Yes thank you. Now its working. I am clueless as to whom i should mark the question as accepted. However, i'll mark @grantmc as the correct answer as he helped me with the views as well. And thank you for helping me out.